# Scala deserialization: class not found

Tags: scala, serialization, deserialization, scala-2.10

I'm trying to understand the following issue that occurs when trying to serialize/deserialize a very simple data structure:

```
case class SimpleClass(i: Int)

object SerializationDebug {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val c = SimpleClass(0)
    val l1 = List(c)

    serializationSaveToFile("test", l1)
    val l2 = serializationLoadFromFile("test") // .asInstanceOf ...
  }

  def serializationSaveToFile(fn: String, o: Any) {
    val fos = new FileOutputStream(fn)
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)
    oos.writeObject(o)
    oos.close()
  }

  def serializationLoadFromFile(fn: String): Any = {
    val fis = new FileInputStream(fn)
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)
    return ois.readObject()
  }  
}
```

When trying to run this code I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleClass` in the deserialization step. The current results of my investigations are:

- The example works when I exchange `SimpleClass` by some built-in type, i.e., I can deserialize `List[Int]` or `List[(Int, Double)]` without a problem. Mixing built-in types with my `SimpleClass` (i.e. having a `List[Any]`) again throws an exception.
- I tried to define `SimpleClass` in other scopes (for instance nested in the object or in the local scope even) but that did not change anything. Also, having a normal (non-case) class extending `Serializable` gives the same result.
- Even more puzzling is that using an `Array[SimpleClass]` instead of `List` does work! Trying other containers confirms this strange inconsistency: having `SimpleClass` as type parameter within an immutable map works, in case of a mutable map I get the exception.

In case it matters: My Scala version is 2.10.0; JDK is 1.7.0.

What is going on here? Is this supposed to fail or is it some kind of bug? My actual problem at hand involves a much more complex data structure (a lot of nesting; mixture of built-in and own classes). Any suggestions to serializing/deserializing this data structure in a minimal-intrusive simple way (i.e. without having to find working combinations of container classes and their type parameters) are also welcome!

Answer (score 9):

This solution works fine for me:

```
val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
  override def resolveClass(desc: java.io.ObjectStreamClass): Class[_] = {
    try { Class.forName(desc.getName, false, getClass.getClassLoader) }
    catch { case ex: ClassNotFoundException => super.resolveClass(desc) }
  }
}
```

of course, when writing object, we use the same way:

```
val ois = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path))
ois.writeObject(myobject)
```

Comment: This looks promising, thank you! Do you understand why we this is needed for `List` but not for `Array` though?

Comment: Works for me, too. However, can you explain why overriding `resolveClass` in this way is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

@trenobus @bluenote10 related to your findings:

I just ran into this today and I think it's because the class' name is different (mangled) when you define it in the console. For instance, I serialized a class `One` from scala

```
> import java.io._
import java.io._
> case class One(s: String, b: Boolean)
defined class One
> new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data")) writeObject One("abc", true)
```

I then tried to deserialize it in java from the same file, having prepared a similar class named `One` in the top level (I made SerialVersionUIDs be the same as well, didn't include it here since it didn't matter), but got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$One
```

Suggesting that scala (rightfully) creates a new JVM class each time you define a class, and presumably keeps an internal mapping so that you can refer to it by its defined name (`One`).

Similarly, because each such class is different in JVM, if you redefine class `One` in that same scala console, and then try to deserialize from the `data` file, you'll get an object of the original class (not of the new class that you redefined).

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand your point, but this sounds as if the deserialization should always fail? Is it possible to extend the explanation why it works for some containers, while it fails for others?

Comment: It shouldn't fail. It should only fail if you create a class in the console, serialize it, then quit the console, and finally try to load it from somewhere else.

Comment: Indeed I am experiencing the same problem as you with your code - funnily though, I can deserialize that file just fine with some java code instead (that has scala-library.jar in its classpath), and I haven't even redefined SimpleClass in Java - it's being loaded from the same scala class.

Answer (score -1):

Works if SimpleClass extends Serializable.

Comment: Case classes automatically extend `Serializable`.

Comment: ... exactly, and that is why I mentioned extending `Serializable` only for the non-case-class case. Thank you anyway for trying to help. I take from your answer that you successfully tested it? May I ask which Scala version?

Comment: Works if I extend SimpleClass with either Serializable or serializable in Scala Worksheet in eclipse. Scala version 2.10.1.

Comment: And now it works even if I don't extend. I swear it failed before just the way the OP said. But I haven't been able to replicate it.

Comment: Beginning to think this has something to do with REPL. Using scala 2.9.2 in sbt, it fails with ClassNotFoundException in readObject consistently. But if I put the code in a file, compile and run it, it works fine.

Comment: Same results with Scala 2.10.1, in and out of sbt: fails and works, respectively.

Comment: Very strange: In my case it fails in both REPL and my sbt projects :(.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an immutable list.  Using play-2.1.1 and scala 2.10.  I get the same exact results as OP.  Anyone solved this yet?