# Correct Way to Reference a Serialized Class in Scala

Tags: java, scala, serialization

I am trying to reference another class that has been serialized in Scala and I am new to Java in general. Here is the code sample I am having problems with

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._

class testcl extends Serializable {

  val teststr = "serializestring"

}


class revivetest {

    val file = "file.serial"

    val fis = new FileInputStream(file)
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)

 val revived = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[testcl]

 }
```

Here is the behavior when I load the class through the REPL:

> scala> val test = new revivetest

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testcl
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at revivetest.(:26)
    at .(:20)
    at .()
    at .(:7)
    at .()
    at $print()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:760)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:805)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:717)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:581)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:588)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:591)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:882)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:837)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:83)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

> Question: What is the correct way to reference another class that has been serialized in order to avoid the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: You saved object in another REPL session, right?

Comment: yes it gives the same error when I compile the code and use a unit test

Comment: and that is strange -- the problem with REPL is that it wraps your expressions in proxy objects and between different definitions the very same class may have quite different names. How are you saving your object? How are you running that unit test?

Comment: I was also having very strange issues with serialization, which I never fully understood. In [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386252/scala-deserialization-class-not-found), what I was trying to achieve was even more trivial. Maybe one of the answers in that question may help you.